# Unable to get request body inside RequestFilterAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

In my .NET Core 3.1 app I need to log out any requests with a status code greater than 400 on my controller POST action.

To do this I have created the following `ResultFilterAttribute`

```
   public class LogFailureResponseFilter : ResultFilterAttribute
   {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public LogFailureResponseFilter(ILogger<LogFailureResponseFilter> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext context)
        {
            var statusCode = context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode;
            if (statusCode >= 400)
            {
                using var reader = new StreamReader(context.HttpContext.Request.Body);
                var body = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result; // <--- this is always null

                _logger.LogWarning($"Request failed for route path {context.HttpContext.Request.Path} with status code {statusCode}. The payload was {body}");
            }

            base.OnResultExecuted(context);
        }
   }
```

I have enabled buffering as per [this Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59076601) that describes how to re-read a request body in `Startup.cs` as follows:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) => {
                context.Request.EnableBuffering();
                await next();
            });
```

**Whenever I try to read the body it is always null - can anyone help please?**

Edit: I've attempted to seek to the beginning of the stream with the following code but it results in `System.NotSupportedException`

```
var bodyStream = context.HttpContext.Request.Body;
bodyStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
using var reader = new StreamReader(bodyStream);
var body = reader.ReadToEndAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Try seeking to the beginning of the stream.

Comment: @abduscoj I've updated my original post - when I do that I get a `System.NotSupportedException`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513305/5298150

Comment: @abdusco did you see that I am already doing that in my original post? ^^

Comment: Why are you calling `ReadToEndAsync` instead of `ReadToEnd()`? This isn't an async method.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your bodystream code under

```
services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.InvalidModelStateResponseFactory = context =>
            {
```

and it worked fine! Try to register it in startup.